# Scripts not running as www-data on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, www-data

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Every other apache setup I've used defaults to running scripts as www-data.

This one, however, is running everything as my username on the server and it is really messing things up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  httpd.conf is untouched.

Comment: What else did you install on it? What changes did you make?

Comment: The only major change was adding an SSL cert to the server. Nothing has been installed or changed yet.  The server is still relatively new.

Comment: That's the wrong answer. Nuke it from orbit, start over, and **document everything you do**.